# Success_url = "detail/int:pk"

Tags: python, django, url

```
class EditBlog(UpdateView):
    model = Entry
    template_name = 'entry/edit.html'
    success_url = "/"
    fields = ['entry_title', 'entry_text']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.entry_author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

i want to put in my success URL the name of the path because the URL of my detail page has a PK with it and it's not working the way i want

Comment: You can use the [get_success_url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_success_url) and the [object attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView.object)

Comment: i didn't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView) has a [method for getting the url to redirect to after the form is successfully saved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_success_url), which defaults to the [success_url attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.success_url).

You could have something like:

```py
from django.urls import reverse
class EditBlog(UpdateView):
    #Your other lines of code
    ...
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("your url name", args=[self.object.pk])
```